# How to catch double page fault (memory mapped file read error) in .NetCore on Linux?

Tags: linux, .net-core, memory-mapped-files

I am randomly reading files in .NetCore on Linux in Docker. For better speed I have file memory mapped, so actual reading is just Span.CopyTo. But what happens when there is IO failure, whole app will crash, but I would like to catch this error and possibly retry later. On the other hand I want to catch this error only when it happens inside that specific Span.CopyTo, so global SIGSEGV handler cannot just ignore error and continue or at least not always.

Probability of failure is probably higher because it actually runs in Cloud (Azure), and disk is not local (so network failure could result in this crash too).

Answer (score 0):

Application used also ChakraCore and signal handler of ChakraCore broke DotNetCore signal handler for SIGSEGV, which crashed application instead of just throwing AccessViolationException.